# How to push object in array of objects in angular 6

Tags: angular

```
cart(){

   let itemList= this.orderService.getCart()
   let obj = {
     quantity : 1
   }
   itemList.push(obj);
   this.product = itemList
  console.log("get products",this.product);
}
```

this is my component.ts file and iam getting array of objects, i want to push an object "quantity" with value "0" in an array of obejcts.
i have this response

```
this.orderService.getCart() = [{id: 48, title: "Mango Juices", price: "30", category: "juices"}]
```

and now when i am going to push i get this result....

```
0:{id: 48, title: "Mango Juices", price: "30", category: "juices"}

1:{quantity: 1}
```

Comment: It seems you are mixing objects and arrays.
There is ONE Object in the array. And it seems you don´t want to push a second value onto this array, but to give the one object in the array an additional attribute "quantitiy". Am i right?

Comment: yes i want to add "quantity" attribute in id:48 object

Comment: The push() method adds new items to the end of an array. What you want is to add a new property to the JavaScript object. Refer to the answer by @Sanoj_V

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If i understood your question you need something like that

```
ngOnInit() {
    let itemList = [{ id: 48, title: "Mango Juices", price: "30", category: "juices" }]
    itemList.forEach((key) => {
      key["quantity"] = 0;
    })
    this.product = itemList
    console.log("get products", this.product); //[{id: 48, title: "Mango Juices", price: "30", category: "juices", quantity: 0}]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`[{id: 48, title: "Mango Juices", price: "30", category: "juices"}]` is an array of objects.

To push a property to your object, you just simply take your object and add your new property:

```
let itemList = [{ id: 48, title: "Mango Juices", price: "30", category: "juices" }] 
itemList[0]["quantity"] = 1;
```

If you want to add the new property for all object in the array, the answer of @Sanoj_V is for that.

Plunker works:https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qne3cl